# Increasing a DEM by different values

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, dem

[image: DEM INCREASE]

I have a DEM of a riverbed and i want to know if the elevation can be increased by different values on the left and right side of it and in between them the values to increase with an average of the two values as shown in the photo.
Basically, on the left side, the height will be increased by 25 from 10 to 35 while on the right the values will be increased by 35 from 10 to 45. The values in between them will be increased with a linear average so basically, the middle value of 15 will be increased by 30 and will get to 45. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: How about (1) Create shapefile of 2 points (35m and 25m) (2) Interpolate the shapefile (3) Add the DEM and the interpolated surface ?

Comment: You have tags for QGIS and ArcGIS Desktop but have not told us which you have used to try and do this, and what you have tried.